# Bouncy Castle ASN1 retrieving objects from BERTaggedObject

Tags: java, bouncycastle, asn.1

I am using Bouncy Castle to decode BER X.690 ASN.1 files.

Here is part of ASN.1 mapping file:

```
CallEventRecord ::= CHOICE
{
    sgsnPDPRecord [20] SGSNPDPRecord,
}

SGSNPDPRecord ::= SET
{
    recordType [0] CallEventRecordType,
    networkInitiation [1] NetworkInitiatedPDPContext OPTIONAL,
    servedIMSI [3] IMSI,
    servedIMEI [4] IMEI OPTIONAL
}
```

I am able to successfully read object from input file. And calling `toString` method on `BERTaggedObject` `berObj` gives:

> [20][[0]#12, [3]#12191031148270f3, [4]#5302816004686062,]

You can see `SGSNPDPRecord`'s tag `[20]`,  `[0]#12` is recordType and it's content, everything is done well here I checked it with ASN1 Dump Utility.
I am stuck with extracting `SGSNPDPRecord` member fields (`recordType`, `networkInititation`, etc).

I am not sure how should I extract fields and their berTags from `BERTaggedObject` `berObj`.

```
public class SGSNPDPRecord extends ASN1Object
{
Integer recordType;
Boolean networkInitiation;
String servedIMSI;
String servedIMEI;

private static int SGSNPDP_RECORD_BER_TAG = 20;

public SGSNPDPRecord(BERTaggedObject berObj) throws IOException {

        int tagNo = berObj.getTagNo();

        // Returns tag number 20, this one is OK
        if (tagNo != SGSNPDP_RECORD_BER_TAG )
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Tag Number!");
            return;
        }

        // How to get here someObject that will check BER Tags of primitive fields recordType, networkInitiation ... and read content from the specific ber tag
        switch ( someObj.getApplicationTag() ) 
        {
            case 0: 
                this.recordType = new Integer( someObj.getContents()[0] );
                break;
            case 1:
                this.networkInitiation = new Boolean(new String( someObj.getContents()[0], "UTF-8"));
                break;
            case 3: 
                this.servedIMSI = new String(someObj.getContents(), "UTF-8");
                break;
            case 4: 
                this.servedIMEI = new String(someObj.getContents(), "UTF-8");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
}

@Override
public ASN1Primitive toASN1Primitive()
{
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the input file?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you the whole file since it has private data encoded. I can give a beginning of it.  B4 80 80 01 12 83 08 12 19 10 31 92 58 95 F0 84 08 53 34 40 80 21 83 89 20 00 00 , this sequence would equal to berTags 0, 3 and 4 (recordType, servedIMSI, servedIMEI). For encoding undefined length was used. end-of-contents octets appear where an ordinary the 00 and 00 appear as identifier and
length octets, respectively. Length octets. One octet, 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using BouncyCastle 1.56. If you're using a version <= 1.46, the code might not be the same, because in version 1.47 there were [lots of significant changes in the API](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Porting+from+earlier+BC+releases+to+1.47+and+later).

First I've got the data you provided in the comments and built the tagged object corresponding to `CallEventRecord`:

```
String s = "B480800112830812191031925895F0840853344080218389200000";
ASN1InputStream in = new ASN1InputStream(Hex.decode(s));
BERTaggedObject callEventRecord = (BERTaggedObject) in.readObject();
in.close();
```

I've just printed the tag and the content, just to make sure it's the same as yours:

```
System.out.println(callEventRecord.getTagNo()); // 20
System.out.println(callEventRecord.getObject()); // [[0]#12, [3]#12191031925895f0, [4]#5334408021838920]
```

The output:

> 20
>   [[0]#12, [3]#12191031925895f0, [4]#5334408021838920]

So, the tag is correct (20), and the content matches the same structure. Let's move on.

---

I've just checked the value of `callEventRecord.getObject().getClass()` and it's a `org.bouncycastle.asn1.BERSequence`, which (according to the ASN.1 definition above) corresponds to `SGSNPDPRecord`. Then I looped through its elements, just to check their types:

```
// get the SGSNPDPRecord
BERSequence sgsnPDPRecord = (BERSequence) callEventRecord.getObject();
for (int i = 0; i < sgsnPDPRecord.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(sgsnPDPRecord.getObjectAt(i).getClass());
}
```

The result was 3 elements, all with the type `org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERTaggedObject`. Then I modified the loop to check the contents of each one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sgsnPDPRecord.size(); i++) {
    DERTaggedObject obj = (DERTaggedObject) sgsnPDPRecord.getObjectAt(i);
    // get the value with obj.getObject()
    switch (obj.getTagNo()) {
        case 0: // CallEventRecordType
            break;
        case 1: // NetworkInitiatedPDPContext
            break;
        case 3: // IMSI
            break;
        case 4: // IMEI
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Inside the loop, you just call `obj.getObject()` to get the corresponding value for each tag. In my test, all elements were instances of `org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROctetString`, but only with the ASN.1 definition above I can't tell how each field should be handled.

So, you should get the corresponding value with `obj.getObject()` and treat this value according to each field's definition.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for. It seems like I used code older code examples from net, no wonder none of them was working since I am using 1.57 BouncyCastle.

Comment: @SimpleThings You're welcome, glad to help! If you found this answer useful and it solved your problem, please consider accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (and perhaps upvote it, when you have enough rep to do it - but only if you found this useful, you're not obliged to do it)

Comment: I accidentaly hit ENTER key without finishing the whole post, I still do not have rep to upvote your answer. What I also wanted to ask is it possible to call getTagNo method on BERSequence sgsnPDPRecord like you did above with objects (in this case ber tag would be 20 for sgsnPDPRecord ). Also what data type should be used to handle ASN.1 Sequences. For example if I had ASN.1 file: http://textuploader.com/djvdp, where field listOfTrafficVolumes is sequence of ChangeOfCharCondition. Sorry for not posting the whole code here, I didn't have enough charachters left to post it here.

Comment: @SimpleThings You can't upvote, but you can accept it (if you found helpful and it solved your problem). Anyway, `sgsnPDPRecord` is a sequence, so it doesn't have a tag (the elements inside this sequence have tags). And to handle ASN.1 sequences, you could use either `BERSequence` or `DERSequence` (both extends `ASN1Sequence`, so you could also use it as well - and some implementations are also using `DLSequence`, but I believe all of them work fine for sequences, I really don't know all the details that differ one from another)

Comment: @SimpleThings The only thing I know is that `BERSequence` is used for indefinite-length sequences, while `DLSequence` is for definite-length (not sure about `DERSequence` though). Anyway, when creating a structure, I usually use `ASN1Sequence`, and when parsing, I use whatever is returned by BouncyCastle

Comment: @SimpleThings Oh, now I get it. The `CallEventRecord` is a tagged object, which can contain just an object with a tag 20, and this object is a `SGSNPDPRecord`. But the `SGSNPDPRecord` is a SET (which is implemented as a `BERSequence`, and this object itself doesn't have a `getTagNo()` (this is a property of the `CallEventRecord` object). I hope it's more clear now. Anyway, if you're having trouble with some other things, I suggest you to post another question, specifically about it (so you'll have more space to post the code and so on)

Comment: Hugo thank you one more time for your help. I will post another thread if I will have more questions. All the best!